# For what "A" in "CMYK(A)" and "RGB(A)" stand for?

Tags: gimp, cmyk, rgb

I ran across these abbreviations while [studying GIMP documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-introduction-whats-new.html). I know the meaning of CMYK and RGB, but I assume A stands for "Alpha"? No help from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is alpha. On File formats, the alpha channel or mask is automatically generated if the format allows it.

It is also used for example as a color notation on CSS for web pages.